# Audio but not Video plays when playing from /raw folder

Tags: android, video, android-videoview

I've looked through all the previous questions I could find on this, but I haven't found anything that actually works to fix the fact that the video won't play. I'm using an h.264 encoded .mp4 file, and I'm sending the address of the R.raw.[video name] via an Intent extra from the main Activity. That part, at least, is working, since the appropriate video's audio loads with working playback controls when I push the "play video" button in the main layout, I just can't get the video itself working and it's making me nuts.

Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;


public class VideoPlayer extends Activity {
private VideoView video;
private MediaController playbackControls;
public static final String iValue = "iValue";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video);
    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int playMe = extras.getInt(iValue, 0);

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + playMe);

    playbackControls = new MediaController(this);
    video.setMediaController(playbackControls);

    video.setVideoURI(uri);
    video.start();

}
}
```

So everything I've looked at indicates that this is fairly standard code, and that it should be working. Is there something I'm missing about precisely which codec I need to be using? Is there a size limit for these things?

I *did* get it to play a super-crappy .3gp file, but not one that was at an even remotely acceptable bitrate. You could barely identify the blobs in the video as humans, and the audio sounded like it was coming from the bottom of a well. A larger .3gp file came up as completely unplayable.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*4/16/11 - A follow up for anyone who comes across this searching: Finally tracked down a real device I could use to debug and the video played perfectly with the above setup. Good to know the emulator's complete crap at playing video.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes the emulator does not render video only audio. So if you are debugging videos in the emulator just listen for the audio and most likely it will work on the device.